# Is it possible to change a datagrid column datatype based on a condition?

Tags: c#, excel, types, datagridview

[Snippet of the excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7xVZ.png)

As can be seen in the Width column, there are some irregular values like `"H:15 ,T:5, W:8.5"`

For cells like `59cm`and `18.50cm` I can just remove the cm when reading into the datagrid so that's fine

When reading the excel table into the datagridview, I set the datagridview column for "Width" as double

**Snippet of my working code**

```
        bomTable = new DataTable("BomTable");
        bomTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        bomTable.Columns.Add("Vendor", typeof(string));
        bomTable.Columns.Add("PartName", typeof(string));
        bomTable.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(double));
        bomTable.Columns.Add("WeightUnit", typeof(string));
        bomTable.Columns.Add("Width", typeof(double)); //set as double
        bomTable.Columns.Add("Width Unit", typeof(string));
```

Naturally, I cannot assign those irregular values into the Width Column as it is, so is it possible to change its datatype based on a condition? Like for example

**Example Code**

```
if (excelRange.Cells[fabricHeaderRow + 1, j].Value2.Contains("H") || 
excelRange.Cells[fabricHeaderRow + 1, j].Value2.Contains("T") ||
excelRange.Cells[fabricHeaderRow + 1, j].Value2.Contains("W"))
{
  bomTable.Columns["Width"].DataType = typeof(string);
}
```

If there's any other workaround, I'd welcome them too

Comment: Why not assign typeof(string) all the time?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably better, but I'm just wondering whether the Example code is possible to implement?

Comment: You can't change a DataGridViewColumns type after it is created. You can however create a new column during runtime and remove the old one and more or less replace them with each other. You will need to populate the rows again though so really wouldn't recommend that. Assign a type that works with the values or format your values in a manner that the column can accept the data being inserted.

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess I'll set it as string then